# Does "1-2 Day Delivery" of a US passport use USPS or a private delivery service?

Tags: passports, us-citizens

When applying for a U.S. passport, besides the expedited service, there is also a [1-2 Day Delivery](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast.html) offered.

My travel isn't until late August or early September, so I don't think that expedited service is needed. However, I keep seeing [reports of postal service delays](https://news.google.com/search?q=postal+service+delays), so I'm concerned that the routine "10-12 weeks" might stretch longer if I have to rely on the US Postal Service to get me my new passport.

Does the State Department use the U.S. Postal Service or a private service such as FedEx for 1-2 Day Delivery?

Comment: They probably use USPS Priority Mail Express. In any case it shouldn't be affected by most postal delays; it is a premium money-back-guaranteed service.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/67924/1362 thinks it's FedEx Overnight but offers no basis for that assertion.

Comment: If I'm reading [the USPS's own service reports correctly](https://about.usps.com/what/performance/service-performance/), they seem to imply that something like 80–90% of mailpieces are delayed for 3 days or less relative to their service standards.  If that's correct, it's unlikely to make a huge difference to you.